# How to get from $3\int_{-1}^0 (x^3-x) dx \,\,\,- \,\,\, 3\int_0^1 (x^3-x) dx$ to $6\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Homework problem:  Set up the definite integral that gives the area of the region.

Two functions are given:

$y_1 = 3(x^3-x)$

$y2 = 0$

The graph of $y1$ runs from x=-1 to x=1.

I've gotten this far:  $3\int_{-1}^0 (x^3-x) dx \,\,\,- \,\,\, 3\int_0^1 (x^3-x) dx$

The book shows two possible solutions:

$6\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)dx$ $\,\,\,$ and $\,\,\,$ $-6\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx$

I'm not quite sure how to get from point A to B and would be grateful if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $f$ is an odd function then *(using the change of variable $t=-x$)*
$$\int_0^a f(x)dx=-\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx$$

Comment: So because we are reversing the upper and lower limits the sign on the entire integral changes?

Comment: Draw an odd function and try to explain this equality geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Substitute $u=-x$ into one or the other of the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

So take $3\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)dx$, let $x=-y\Rightarrow dx=-dy$, when $x=0, y=0$, and when $x=-1, y=1$, so we get:

$3\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)dx=3\int_{1}^0((-y)^3-(-y))(-dy)=3\int_0^1(y-y^3)dy=-3\int_0^1(y^3-y)dy$

$=-3\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx$

Thus: $3\int_{-1}^0(x^3-x)dx-\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx=-3\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx-3\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx=-6\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx$

To find the other solution use the same substitution, in the other integral.